# How do I make python only ask for user input once in def main()?

Tags: python

Here's the code

```
# Number guessing game

# Import any libraries here
from random import randrange

#def user_integer():
 #   ''' get what user's integer here'''
  #  x = int(input("Enter integer to play"))


def random_int(size):
    """ This function takes in an integer size that indicates the
    length of the list of integers beginning at 1 and ending 
    at size, including size. It returns a random integer between 1 and size.
    """
    return randrange(1, size+1)

# Test out the function
#random_int(10)

def new_guess():
    '''user input for a new number'''
    x = input("what's your guess?")
    x = int(x)
    #while x!= -4:
     #   compare(user_num, computer_num)
    return x

def compare(user_num, computer_num):
    ''' compares size of numbers and prints winner'''
    user_num = new_guess()
    computer_num = int(random_int(1000))
    if user_num > computer_num:
        print ("user wins")
    elif user_num == computer_num:
        print ("it's a tie")
    elif user_num < computer_num:
        print ("robots win")
    else:
        print("wrong input")


def main():
    ''' control center, allowing me to use multiple functions to pass information '''
    # Write your algorithm here
    computer_num = random_int(1000)
    user_num = new_guess()
    print("You guessed", user_num)
    print("The robot's number is",computer_num)
    compare(user_num, computer_num)

    
main()
```

This gives me:

> what's your guess? 85 #input

> You guessed 85

> The robot's number is 540 #random number

> what's your guess? 85 #it makes user input again

> robots win

Everything prints that is supposed to print. However, since I called `user_num = new_guess()`, it makes the user input a number once there and then again for the function `compare(user_num, computer_num)`

How do I make it so that a user only inputs a number once to get a response from `compare(user_num, computer_num)`?

Should I call user_num a new name once I get my guess in def main()?

Comment: "However, since I called user_num = new_guess(), it makes the user input a number once there and then again for the function compare(user_num, computer_num)" yes; if you tell the code to do something in two different places, and each of those points in the code is reached once, then it will happen twice overall. Similarly, `computer_num` is also being chosen twice - there just isn't an obvious way to notice.

Comment: So why do you have `user_num = new_guess()` in the function `compare` if you don't want to have it there?

Comment: "How do I make it so that a user only inputs a number once" Do you see where the code says `def compare(user_num, computer_num):`? In your own words, what do you think is the purpose of the `user_num, computer_num` part of that line? Do you see how it relates to the part of the code that calls the function (`compare(user_num, computer_num)`, inside the `main` function)? Do you know what the words *parameter* and *argument* mean, in programming?

Comment: You mistakenly duplicated `user_num = new_guess()` in the `computer` function.

Comment: @tdelaney *`compare` function

Comment: Thank you to all of you for helping me out and showing me how to look at the code. 

@Matthias, I simply wasn't aware I didn't want it there.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I'm aware of parameter but only peripherally do I know what an argument is. Thanks for pointing that out for me =)

Comment: An argument is the thing that you use in order to say what the value of the parameter will be.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're getting input for twice. In main function, you get `computer_num` random number and `user_num` input. And then you call `compare()` function, which have these both parameters.

You can delete 2 lines of code from `compare()` function. It should look like this:

```
def compare(user_num, computer_num):
    ''' compares size of numbers and prints winner'''
    if user_num > computer_num:
        print ("user wins")
    elif user_num == computer_num:
        print ("it's a tie")
    elif user_num < computer_num:
        print ("robots win")
    else:
        print("wrong input")
```